# My first attempt at a Vowelburger™ puzzle

Tags: word, wordplay, language, english, letters

*<sup>You can find the other Vowelburger™ Riddles [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=vowelburger+is%3Aquestion)</sup>*
I ordered 9 Vowelburgers™ with buns and meat at the **linguistic restaurant** - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ??? | catch |
| ??? | nickname |
| ??? | seal |
| ??? | type |
| ??? | sharp |
| ??? | stem |
| ??? | chip |
| ??? | mammal |
| ??? | shape |

The buns are [pulmonic consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_pulmonic_consonant_chart_with_audio) and the meats are [vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio) so the transcription of the Vowelburgers™ may not share the same consonants.

**HOWEVER: Today, the restaurant is offering a special deal: burgers with two patties are also available.** In other words, the meat can also be [diphthongs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong#English).

What burgers did I order?
Write your answers either as English words or using the IPA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your buns are

> k and n

and the burgers are

> catch: con (not sure if this works?)
>  nickname: Ken (probably, thanks @JeremyDover)
>  seal: can (*canning* food is sort of *sealing* it)
>  type: kin
>  sharp: keen
>  stem: cane
>  chip: coin (as in poker chips)
>  mammal: [kine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kine)
>  shape: cone

Comment: You're on the right track.

Comment: Maybe rot13(avpxanzr:Xra)?

Comment: Congratulations! You got them all.